# read a csv file in 3 columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, split

I want to read a csv file with 3 columns: "source","target","genre_ids" with python

```py
df = pd.read_csv('edges1.csv',encoding="ISO-8859-1",  delimiter=';;', header=None,skiprows=1, names=columns,engine="python",index_col=False )
data = pd.concat([df.iloc[:,0].str.split(',', expand=True).rename(columns:=['source','target','genre_ids']), axis==1])
```

I want to get:

```
source          target    genre_ids
apple           green      21
strawberry       red       23
son on
```

edge1.csv contains:

```
source,target,genre_ids
apple,green,21
strawberry,red,23
and so on
```

when I read the `edges1.csv` file I have data on only one column. To separate the columns I found the concat method online which splits the columns, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please update your question and put there sample of content of `edges1.csv`?

Comment: Also make a [mcve] that can be run and reproduce the problem *with no additions or changes to the code*.

Comment: @Elly just `df = pd.read_csv('edges1.csv')` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sample data, it seems the delimiter is `,`, but in your code you're explicitly setting it to `;;`. Using the correct delimiter should solve the problem:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('edges1.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1",  delimiter=',', header=None, skiprows=1, names=columns,e ngine="python", index_col=False )
# Here -----------------------------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `read_csv` call uses `delimiter=';;'`. Remove it to use the default delimiter, which is `','`.

```
df = pd.read_csv('edges1.csv',encoding="ISO-8859-1", header=None, skiprows=1, names=columns,engine="python", index_col=False )
```